# local variables in linux

Tags: linux, subshell

When we export a local variable declared within a current shell does it get passed to future sub shells,processes , child processes or future child processes?
I was told it get passed to future sub shells. Is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simple test will answer you by itself:

```
$ VAR1="Hello, World!"
$ echo "${VAR1}"
Hello, World!
$ bash
$ echo "${VAR1}"

$ export VAR1="Hello, World!"
$ echo "${VAR1}"
Hello, World!
$ bash
$ echo "${VAR1}"
Hello, World!
$
```

Breaking it down:

No export ...

```
$ VAR1="Hello, World!"
$ echo "${VAR1}"
Hello, World!
$ bash
$ echo "${VAR1}"

$
```

... leads to `VAR1` not being defined in the child.

While with `export` ...

```
$ export VAR1="Hello, World!"
$ echo "${VAR1}"
Hello, World!
$ bash
$ echo "${VAR1}"
Hello, World!
$
```

... leads to `VAR1` being defined in the child.

Comment: so VAR1 can get passed into child ?

Comment: It **is** *passed* to the child environment, yes.

Comment: but it will not be passed to child processes right?

Comment: When `bash` is called after the export, it is a child process of the parent shell.

Answer (score 2):

Just try?

```
$ export foo=bar
$ bash
$ echo $foo
bar
$ bash
$ echo $foo
bar
$ exit
$ exit
$
```

tl;dr: Yes.